# Is it possible to let the entire R Studio program run from Python?

Tags: python, r

So basically, looking around stack overflow I have been able to find subprocess and try to run the program from Python's side. I guess it worked partially because while the R Studio program pops up, nothing runs it just shows up and does nothing. Is there a way I can modify the code so that the entire R code runs just by using Python? Thank you!

```
import subprocess

ShowText = input("Please enter your name: ")

myfile = open("logo2.txt","w+")

font = ImageFont.truetype('verdanab.ttf', 24)
size = font.getsize(ShowText)
image = Image.new('1', size, 1)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), ShowText, font=font)

myfile.write(f"{size[0]}\t{size[1]}\n")
for row in range(size[1]): 
    line = []
    for col in range(size[0]):
        if image.getpixel((col, row)):
            line.append('0\t')
        else:
            line.append('1\t')
    myfile.write('\n')
    myfile.write(''.join(line))

myfile.close()
 
subprocess.call([r"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/rstudio", '-f', r'C:/Users/Me/Documents/Trials/Plotting.R'])
```

Comment: R Studio is an IDE.  You want to call R (or possibly RScript) directly instead.

Comment: Yes that does it! I tried doing R directly before but instead of "-f" doing "--vanilla" worked!

Comment: Check out `rpy2` (second answer in the linked question). It is... just a better way of doing this.